# Linear Regression Goodness of Fit Test & Partitioning a Data Set to Approximate Linearity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, linear

I have a stochastic mapping from vectors $X$ to $Y$ with a great deal of variance and a linear regression model $Y = a+bX$. Is there a simple statistical test which can tell me whether or not this model is a good fit?

Secondary question, and this is a bit more niche: is there any algorithm for deciding how to partition the domain of my mapping such that each side would fit a linear regression model best? For instance, $Y = <x_0 + x_1^2> + \epsilon$ might be partitioned perpendicular to $<0,1>$, while $Y = <x_0^2 + x_1^2, -x_0^2 - x_1 + 1> + \epsilon$ might be partitioned perpendicular to $<2,1>$ (or in more places). The idea being that an arbitrary set of data could be recursively partitioned into data which could be modeled relatively well via regressions on each subset of $X$'s domain.

If anyone had any suggestions for such an algorithm it'd be appreciated! I have a few ideas but they are awfully messy.

Comment: I would also like to add that the variance of my data set is heteroskedastic and non-normally distributed

Comment: What would it mean to you for you to have a good fit? What about a bad fit?

Comment: That is probably something I should've elaborated on. A 'good fit' would mean no non-linear model performs significantly better in terms of mean squared error on the data set. For instance, a linear model would probably not be a 'good fit' for an underlying quadratic relationship - but might be if the relationship is weak or the data set is small. I guess my issue is the underlying relationship could be arbitrary, and so I feel I need to test against a massive number of alternative models.

Comment: Au contraire! [That quadratic relationship can be modeled with OLS linear regression.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rVviNyIR-fI) // It seems like your question is, “How do I do regression?” Is that about right?

Comment: Not exactly! Even if one uses quadratic predictors, or arbitrarily complex predictors - which beget the problem of overfitting -  there is still no guarantee the regression would model the underlying data. A linear piecewise function, for instance, would probably be very hard to model using any arbitrary set of polynomial predictors. Normally it seems people use neural networks to model data of unknown nature, but I was simply wondering if OLS linear regression could be 'forced' to work by partitioning the model in two where it is a poor fit.